# How do I keep my computer running smoothly?

Tags: windows-10, performance

What steps can I take on a regular basis to keep my Windows 10 computer running top-notch, out of the box smooth? I'd rather not use third-party apps, but I don't mind, as long as my computer is running smoothly afterwards.

Thanks,

Virtuality.

Comment: Is your question purely about performance or do you also want a stable and secure system? For that you need for example regular backups (including checking SMART values with e.g. [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/)) plus application/OS/firmware security updates.

Comment: Both. I would find a step by step regular routine that I could use regularly to effectively keep my computer running smoothly convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, these are the steps to keep a new windows 10 computer running smoothly:

1. Do not install to much third-party apps
2. Be careful to not fill completely the (C:) Disk (the system disk)
3. Check in Task Manager >> Startup, if you have apps that start when the computer is booting (and disable the one that you don't need)
4. Clear the temporaries files in Storage Settings